# write junit test case for hazelcastinstance

Tags: junit, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

This is my class for which I want to write junit tests. Can you please help as how can I write junit tests for `HazelcastInstance` and adding data in map.

```
public class A {

    private A() {
    }    

    private static int ID;

    @Autowired
    public static HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    @Getter
    public static final IMap<String, Map<String, String>> imap;

    static {
        hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(new Config().setInstanceName("hazelcast-newinstance"));  
        vinUUIDmap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("ID");
    }

    public static void addID(String uuid, long ts) {
        Map<String, String> idmap= new HashMap<>();
        idmap.put("timestamp", ts.toString());
        idmap.put("UUID", uuid);
        imap.putIfAbsent(getID().toString(), idmap, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63049711/7066647

Answer (score 1):

Please see Hazelcast's internal unit tests for sample usage. [BasicMapTest](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/test/java/com/hazelcast/map/BasicMapTest.java) can be a good place to start.